# How do i get the innermost item inside a dictionary in python

Tags: python, json, loops, dictionary, yaml

I loaded a file into a dictionary in python. Suppose it look something like this:

```
{'dictionary': {'a': {'second_level': {'data': 'hello'}},
                'b': {'another_level': {'this_one_has_three_levels': {'data': 'hi'}}}}}
```

Assuming that i don't know any of the keys except for the key "data" (therefore i can't do `dictionary[a][data]`) how can i write a function that gets the whole dictionary as an input and outputs something like this:

```
["dictionary>a>second_level>data>'hello'", "dictionary>b>another_level>this_one_has_three_levels>data>'hi'"]
```

this needs to save the whole "path" to the innermost element that are "hello" and "hi".
I guess I need to have some sort of while loop here but I cant figure it out

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: This is a set: `{"hi"}`. Does you dictionary actually have sets?

Comment: I might have done a mistake, i loaded this from a yaml file that has `data: 'hi'` in it. @MarkMeyer

Comment: Please show us a *valid* dictionary.

Comment: Changed the dictionary into a *valid* one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursive approach is usually the simplest if nesting depth is not known in advance. Here is an example with a generator function:

```
def get_data(dct, key):
    if key in dct:
        yield f"{key}>{dct[key]}"
    for k, v in dct.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            for s in get_data(v, key):
                yield f"{k}>{s}"


>>> list(get_data(d, "data"))
['dictionary>a>second_level>data>hello', 
 'dictionary>b>another_level>this_one_has_three_levels>data>hi']
```